# How will I achieve the below requirement with sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a following tables

table1

```
table1_id        name      
1                abc          
2                cde            
3                efg
```

table2

```
table2_id(fkey)     value
  1                 10
  2                 19
  3                 50
```

here table 2 foreign key references table 1 for id. I want the following string format when i query `6:10,8:19,5:50`

above 6,8 and 5 are constants(can hard coded) defined by me where as 10, 19,50 are the values which i receive based on the name column of table1

i,e:to get the value for key 6 in a string:>

```
select table2.value by join 2 table on id where name="abc"
```

next : to get the value for a key 8 is by>

```
select table2.value join 2 table on id where name="cde"
```

and so on

Comment: please format and rephrase your question in a more well-formed manner. everything is mingled together and incomprehensible.

Comment: ....but why 6 for abc and 8 for cde?

Comment: 6 is hard coded(i will mention it in stored proc) the corresponding key should be from table2.value on table1.id=table2.id where table1.name="abc" and so on for 8 where name="cde"

Comment: key 6 will be hard coded in stored proc whose corresponding value should be  from table2.value on table2.id=table1.id where table1.name="abc" and so on for key 8. But how to handle multiple where clause(for key 8 name="cde") in single select if my doubt is valid

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want something like this:

```
select stuff( (select concat(',', v.val, ':', t2.value)
               from table2 t2 join
                    table1 t1
                    on t2.table2_id = t1.table1_id join
                    (values ('abc', 6), ('cde',8 ), ('efg', 5)
                    ) v(name, val)
                    on v.name = t1.name
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 1, '')
```

The subquery without the `for xml path` produces the pairs that you want.  The `for xml path` is just used for string aggregation.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff : its partially giving the result. Problem is that its displaying all the result with common id between them . But the name(i.e: "abc,"cde") also should be present in the table1 only for such it should display accordingly

Comment: @krity . . . " I want the following string format when i query 6:10,8:19,5:50".  That is what this query returns.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff :You didn't understand me properly, I mean to say that suppose there is a table1_id and table2_id entry as 5 in both tables and the corresponding column "name" value is "xyz" in table table_1 which 'I do not mention in the query' still i get values correspond to that in my output string.